# How to add an email with timestamp in a variable? Or is possible? (Katalon)

Tags: groovy, automated-tests, katalon-studio

I want to use a custom Keyword like example:

```
public class alalbala {
    @Keyword
    def email(){

        String myEmailAddress = "test" + System.nanoTime() + "@itest.com";
        return myEmailAddress;
    }
}
```

And this myEmailAddress I want to check on another page like the example in a DB to see if this email is added. I am thinking to add in a variable and then using the variable to see if the email is present but I don't know-how. Can you help me, please!

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us say your `alalbala` class is inside of a package called `myPackage`.

You need to import that class to the script you need to use. And then you can use your method (function) inside your script.

For example:

```
import static myPackage.alalbala.email

def example = email()
println example
```

This will print something like "test722385734582300@itest.com", even though email method is declared in another file.